# Most semantic way to markup a conversation (or interview)?

Tags: html, semantics, semantic-markup

I'm trying to figure out the most semantic way to markup something like this.

```
John: blah blah 
Paul: blah blah 
George: blah blah 
Ringo: blah blah
```

or

```
John:   blah blah 
Paul:   blah blah 
George: blah blah 
Ringo:  blah blah
```

Ideally there'd be the CSS flexibility to do either or to break it into a paragraph with or without the names visible. I considered using the `before:` selector to add the names, but I also want them to be linkable. For example, I'd link to Ringo's twitter profile if he had one. It also should read properly in screenreaders.

Comment: Just a thought: use the `:after` on the speaker tag and set the `content` to ": ". That way, you can have just the conversation in the markup and leave the presentation for CSS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The HTML5 spec [discusses this](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#conversations), the gist of which is:

> Authors are encouraged to mark up conversations using `p` elements and punctuation. Authors who need to mark the speaker for styling purposes are encouraged to use `span` or `b`. Paragraphs with their text wrapped in the `i` element can be used for marking up stage directions.

So, ultimately, something like this:

```
<p><span>John:</span> blah blah</p>

<p><span>Paul:</span> blah blah</p>

<p><span>George:</span> blah blah</p>

<p><span>Ringo:</span> blah blah</p>
```

This would enable styling in the way you describe. You could, of course, also add `class` attributes if necessary. Your instinct not to put the names in CSS with the `:before` selector is a good one--this information should definitely be in the markup.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to put a`q` tag around the spoken text?

Comment: `q` seems to be intended for a quotation within a larger block of text, e.g. `<p>Caesar said, <q>Veni, vidi, vici.</q></p>`. It may be more appropriate to wrap the whole passage in a `blockquote`. HTML5 Doctor has some [discussion on the topic](http://html5doctor.com/blockquote-q-cite/).

Comment: Nice find—I wasn't sure if there was something more than that. Thx!

Comment: The link now (some years later) does not point to the right text anymore. On that page, the deep-link seems to be: ['the HTML5 spec discusses this'](http://w3c.github.io/html/common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements.html#conversations).

Answer (score -7):

hm.

Tip - use xml to mark it up. Should make it easier to work with later

something like `<voice speaker="John"></voice>`

maybe

Comment: OP's talking about html; see the tags.